# How to show Profit or loss percentage for each month in a bar chart?

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart, trendline

I have a bar chart where the first three series represent the expenses and the last series represent the revenue. I want to show the profit or loss for each month in percentage. Below is the image of current graph.

[image]

Here is my code for the same.

```
var s1 = [27362, 45273, 77020, 42059, 23764, 12803];
    var s2 = [15920, 30220, 32800, 21900, 19500, 17300];
    var s3 = [4100, 1800, 7150, 3600, 2400, 2400];
    var s0 = [27208, 46371, 169374, 114879, 35692, 37669];
    var ticks = ['March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August'];

$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2, s3, s0], {
    stackSeries: true,
    animate: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
            location: 'n',
        },
        rendererOptions: {
            fillToZero: true,
            barPadding: 0,
            barMargin: 0,
            barWidth: 55,
            barDirection: 'vertical',
        },
    },
    series: [
        {
            label: 'Equipment',
            color: '#c5b47f'
        },
        {
            label: 'Salaries',
            color: '#eaa228'
        },
        {
            label: 'O&M',
            color: '#4bb2c5'
        },
        {
            label: 'Revenue',
            color: '#579575',
            disableStack: true

        }
    ],
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
            fontSize: '13pt'
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        },
        yaxis: {
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        location: 'e',
        placement: 'outside'
    }
});
```

I want it to show the profit or loss as shown below

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this by three different approaches.

1) First approach is with pointLabels. With pointLabel I have to use `'stackedValue:true'` which does not give me individual value of the series in a stack. Secondly, the position of the pointLabel is above the stacked bar and not above the group.

2) Second approach is to add a trendline. But the problem is y-axis values are in absolute number and the values of the trendline will be in percentage. Is it possible to show the percentage series in the same chart ?

2) Third approach is to calculate the % profit or loss for each month and then display it by inserting a div into the graph for each month. Sounds tricky but is it feasible ?

Any different approach from your side most welcome.